# How to see how many numpy arrays you have allocated

Tags: python, numpy

I have some complex simulation code that defensively copies arrays in different places and in certain conditions to ensure  that I don't accidentally modify data something else is using. However I want to make sure I'm not being too defensive and copying unnecessary. I'd like to see how many arrays have been allocated during a simulation and see if that matches what I expect. Does numpy offer this functionality?

Comment: No, numpy doesn't provide this, and really, creating a new `numpy.ndarray` object might not be exactly what you are looking for. Note, `arr = np.arange(20); arr_view = arr[::2];` now, while these are different objects, they share the same underlying buffer

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from collections.abc import Container

def print_count(variables):
    counter = 0
    for variable in variables:
        if isinstance(variable, np.ndarray):
            counter += 1
        
        elif isinstance(variable, Container):
            for e in variable:
                if isinstance(e, np.ndarray):
                    counter += 1
    print(counter)

print_count(list(locals().values()))
```

Comment: This is not going to be a useful, why do you assume all allocated arrays will be referenced in some local/global namespace?

Comment: I don't see how this is not useful when used wherever / whenever the number of allocated numpy arrays is to be inspected; in the end they exist in _some_ namespace

Comment: No, no they don't. E.g. `mylist = []; mylist.append(np.arange(10))`. Also, this assumes there is a *single* namespace. The OP has some program, which almost certainly, uses many, many different local namespaces.

Comment: Good point. The issue faced by having numpy arrays in .e.g. an iterable could to some degree be addressed by doing futher type checking (could become cumbersome depending on the types involved however). But (apart from manually using the code at the respective places) I don't see any straight-forward way to overcome the issue that comes from having (potentially) many namespaces.